# How to partition bootable drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu in my computer and there is only one drive in my whole hard disk(only one drive which is bootable one ).I want to partition my hard disk in several drives without using live CD or PD ,
is it possible ? 
if yes then how ? 
and if no then what are other options ?

Answer (score 0):

Install gparted to your system using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then boot using - Ubuntu Live CD and select the option "Try Ubuntu" at startup, then your will be able to use Gparted to resizing your Ubuntu root partition.

Hope this helps,

Comment: 1. The OP is asking "without CD or PD" 2. gparted is installed by default on the live CD and on the machine. 3. Installing gparted (even if the OP uninstalled it) is unnecessary... :/